# Making a kiddush for a woman that has hard time finding shidduch

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, shidduchim-dating

There is a belief that if one did not make a kiddush for the birth of his daughter and that woman is having a hard time finding a shidduch, then they should make a kiddush and it will help.

I know from a halachic standpoint there isn't any obligation to make a kiddush, so where did this idea come from?

Comment: Maybe it's because parents who have a strong attachment to their daughter are more likely both to make a kiddush for her and to help her find a shidduch.

Comment: It's a story from some Godol.

Comment: From the title I thought this was going to be a question about making kiddush for an older single girl who doesn’t live with her family.

Comment: Maybe it comes from the idea that she'll meet bachelors at the _kidush_.

Comment: @Alex I edited in the word "a" before the word "kiddush".

Comment: Definitely gets the girl quite a bit of attention. Sponsoring a party for everyone to thhink of ideas for her sounds quite smart...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Rav of Congregation Ahavas Israel, Passaic, NJ debunks the legend about this story [here](https://www.ahavasisrael.org/torah/shortvort_archive/3504/) (edited).

So the idea is a made-up story.

> Rabbi Yaakov Yisrael Kanievsky, known as The Steipler (1899–1985) was
>   reported to have told a father of a woman who was having difficulty in
>   finding a shidduch that the reason she was experiencing such
>   difficulty was the fact that upon her birth her father failed to make
>   a kiddush in her honor. As brochos  are traditionally bestowed upon
>   the new born baby girl for her to grow and marry at the kiddush, since
>   the father did not have a kiddush in her honor no brochus were
>   bestowed and therefore she is now suffering with not finding her
>   ‘bashert’.
>
> This Shtetl Legend appears in Jewish story books and I myself was
>   present at a Kiddush where a Rabbi related the story.
>
> In the Sefer Derech Sicha (volume one page 33) - a compilation of
>   Torah thoughts by Rav Chaim Kanievsky Shlita (the ONLY son of Rabbi
>   Yaakov Yisrael Kanievsky Zt”l) it is related that when he was told of
>   this ‘quote’ from his father he responded: “Who made this up? Wouldn’t
>   I have heard about it?! He never said to make a kiddush in our
>   family.”
>
> I myself asked Rav Chaim about this Shtetl Legend quoted in the name
>   of his father and he debunked it to me as well while adding, “perhaps
>   for the first daughter you could (if you want) make a Kiddush)
>   however, there is no obligation to make a Kiddush for a daughter at
>   all and my father never said there was.”
>
> Ron Yitzchok Eisenman, Rabbi, Congregation Ahavas Israel, Passaic, NJ

Text of Derech Sicha:

[image]

Comment: @sam ... and well done to you for accessing the actual text!

Comment: Was he the only Gadol who this "segula" was cited from? Maybe another Gadol actually did start the trend

Comment: The main point is that it does not have a mekor, because if it did Rav Chaim would know